# MongoDB single/central authSource vs multiple/distributed authSource

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication

When securing a Mongo instance, you can add user credentials and roles into the built-in "admin" database or into any number of other custom databases that you may add to the instance.

It seems to me that having all the credentials and roles stored centrally in the "admin" database would make sense from a management point of view (easy to locate, everything in one place, don't need to connect to multiple databases to find all users, predictability, etc), so why would you use a custom database as the "authSource"? The docs don't explain why you would use "admin" over a custom database or vice versa.

So my question is:

### Is it best practice to store all users and roles in the "admin" database or in each custom database to which that user will be connecting? Why?

Comment: If credentials are dynamic, managed from your application, it makes sense to keep these credentials in user-space database.

Comment: @AlexBlex interesting. Does that assume that your application only uses the single user-space database to which you refer?

Comment: No, think about it as a reseller model. The application authenticates against system db.  It manages client applications, quotas, credentials, etc. Client services are authenticated against user-space db assigned to them.

Comment: @AlexBlex ok I get it now, thanks. What about if credentials are not dynamic and connecting "users" are just service accounts?

Comment: What about it? There are usecase when decentralised auth is handy and plenty of usecases where it is useless. You don't need to use all features of the dbs just because they are available =) There is no a single "best practice" for all scenarios. There are problems and tools to solve them. Some tools are better for particular tasks. When you find the match you get a competitive advantage.